# How to say "see you this weekend?"

Tags: translation, grammar, expressions, phrase

My Mandarin teacher told us “星期四见” to say "see you on Thursday." How would I say "see you this weekend"?

“这个周末见” or “末见这个周”? Or something else entirely? This is being used to end a letter, so I don't need to throw in a “你” right? I'm a bit confused as to whether the verb should come first or last.

谢谢！

Comment: 周末见 don't really need to say "this" unless you want to emphasize it

Comment: Follows the pattern of 明天见.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in another answer, it should be 这个周末见 (which emphasizes that it is *this* weekend) or 周末见.

末见这个周 is incorrect, because it breaks up [周末](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%80%B1%E6%9C%AB#Chinese): the characters comprise the word for "weekend" and must be together. So it must be that 周末 and any qualifers (here possibly 这个) must be *before* 见.

I *could* imagine 你 being thrown in as an object, but it is unnecessary and may sound awkward *unless* part of a larger phrase like in "周末见你啦" (which would appear to work, at least in Cantonese). But this would also change the emphasis of the phrase: 周末见 would suggest that meeting again is a mutual act, whereas the addition of 你 might suggest situations such as the speaker visiting the listener.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `这个周末见`, or just `周末见`, don't say `末见这个周`.

And yes, no need to throw in a `你`.

Answer (score 0):

To say "see you [anytime]" is just "[anytime] 见".

明天见 see you tomorrow
周四见 see you on Thursday
周末见 see you this weekend
明年见 see you next year
2016年见 see you on 2016
etc